# Adding a class with Jquery to JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am displaying the JSON data http://jsfiddle.net/Pmxjk/1/ If the age is less than 25 I want to add a class say "green" how do I implement that. I know Jquery has a .addClass API but how to add it this example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option:

check the age with a ternary operator and conditionally wrap it in a span.

http://jsfiddle.net/7zv9h/

```
  fragment += template.replace( /\{\{FirstName\}\}/, msg.firstName )
      .replace( /\{\{LastName\}\}/,  msg.lastName )
      .replace( /\{\{Age\}\}/,  (msg.Age < 25) ? '<span class="green">'+msg.Age+'</span>' : msg.Age);
```